# Multithreading problem using System.out.print vs println

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following thread which simply prints a dot every 200ms:

```
public class Progress {

    private static boolean threadCanRun = true;
    private static Thread progressThread = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() {
            while (threadCanRun) {
                System.out.print('.');
                System.out.flush();
                try {
                    progressThread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
        }
    });

    public static void stop()
    {
        threadCanRun = false;
        progressThread.interrupt();
    }

    public static void start()
    {
        if (!progressThread.isAlive())
        {
            progressThread.start();
        } else
        {
            threadCanRun = true;
        }
    }

}
```

I start the thread with this code (for now):

```
 System.out.println("Working.");
 Progress.start();


 try {
        Thread.sleep(10000); //To be replaced with code that does work.
 } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

 Progress.stop();
```

What's really strange is this:

If I use `System.out.println('.');` , the code works exactly as expected. (Apart from the fact that I don't want a new line each time).

With `System.out.print('.');`, the code waits for ten seconds, and then shows the output.

`System.out.println`:

> ```
>      Print dot, wait 200ms, print dot, wait 200ms etc...
> ```

`System.out.print`:

> ```
>      Wait 5000ms, Print all dots
> ```

What is happening, and what can I do to go around this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried this:

```
private static synchronized void printDot()
{
    System.err.print('.');
}
```

and printDot() instead of `System.out.print('.');`
It still doesn't work.

**EDIT2:**

Interesting. This code works as expected:

```
        System.out.print('.');
        System.out.flush();  //Makes no difference with or without
        System.out.println();
```

This doesn't:

```
        System.err.print('.');
        System.err.flush();
        System.out.print('.');
        System.out.flush();
```

**Solution:** The issue was netbeans related. It worked fine when I run it as a jar file from java -jar.

This is one of the most frustrating errors I have seen in my life. When I try to run this code with breakpoints in debug mode, everything works correctly.

Comment: This works as expected for me (prints out a dot every 200ms for about 10 sec, then quits).

Comment: @MichaelM. Please tell me what JDK and OS you are using. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stdout is line buffered.
Use stderr, or flush the PrintStream after each print.

Comment: @lngo I have modified the code and got the exact same error. Even using System.err.print gives the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

(This is weird code -- there are much cleaner ways to write and manage threads. But, that's not the issue.)

Your IDE must be buffering by line. Try running it directly on the command line. (And hope that the shell isn't buffering either, but shouldn't.)

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the issue. (Near the solution line). Please show me the cleaner way to write and manage the thread, I am keen to learn. You may edit your answer or my question if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The `println` method automatically flushes the output buffer, the `print` method not. If you want to see the output immediately, a call to `System.out.flush` might help.

Comment: I tried flushing the stream but it didn't work. See comment above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the println() method is synchronized

Comment: Is there anything I can do to synchronize the print method?

Comment: i have tried blocks also, but it does not seem to work, this is just my thought, i do not know if I am right. I just know abouth the synchronized println() because our program worked good and when the println()'s were taken out it broke.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer; the asker, David, requested that I follow up on a secondary point about rewriting the threading. I am only able to post code this way.)

```
public class Progress {

  private ProgressRunnable progressRunnable = new ProgressRunnable();

  public void start() {
    new Thread(progressRunnable).start();
  }

  public void stop() {
    progressRunnable.stop();
  }

  private class ProgressRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (running.get()) {
        System.out.print('.');
        System.out.flush();
        try {
          Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }
    }

    private void stop() {
      running.set(false);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Progress progress = new Progress();
    progress.start();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    progress.stop();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, with `System.out.print()` and `System.out.flush()`. The code works for me, except for the code:

```
while (!threadCanRun)
            {
                 Thread.yield();
            }
```

in Progress class. Doing that, the thread is pausing allowing other thread to execute, as you can see in the thread api [page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29). Removing this part, the code works.

But I don't understand why do you need the `yield` method. If you call `Progress.stop()`, this will cause to invoke the `yield` method. After the thread will stop with `interrupt`, (after waiting a huge amount of time on my pc).
If you want to allow other threads executing and the current thread pausing, consider the `join()` method.

If you want to stop the current thread, maybe you can consider to remove the 
`while(!threadCanRun)` loop, or place `Thread.currentThread().join()` before `Thread.interrupt()` in the `stop()` method to wait for the completion of other threads, or simply call the `p.stop()` method .

Take a look to these [posts](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/12990-difference-between-thread-yield-thread-sleep-methods.html).

Comment: I hope I'm not going crazy. I removed Thread.yield() and increased the delay to ten seconds. Modified code above. **The program first waits for ten seconds, then prints out many dots on the same line.** Netbeans, Windows 7, JDK 6 SE Update 27. 3GB Ram + Amd Athlon 64X2 4800+ (Old dual code 2.8Ghz).

Comment: Also make sure you did not insert a breakpoint anywhere in the program. If you do, (and run it in debug mode) it works absolutely fine.

Comment: @David I didn't inserted any breakpoint. Currently I'm running on an Ubuntu machine, with Oracle JDK 6 SE. I tested your code with a main class, containing the static void main method, creating a new Progress object. The code works, printing a dot each 200 ms.

Comment: Did you test the code from the main method exactly as indicated (including the Thread.sleep(10000)) ?

Comment: I tried many many different combinations to try to get it to work, static, yield instead of sleep - it simply won't work unless I use println. Maybe there is another way of flushing.

Comment: @David Please notice I used your combination as written in the question, with print() and flush().

Comment: Do you have windows installed by any chance? Could you try it on that if you have time to spare?

Comment: @David I tested the code on Windows 7 as you requested. I have also recompiled it. Same behavior as previously on Ubuntu. The code without yield() and with print() and flush(),even with Thread.sleep(10000), works for me. It prints a dot every 200 ms.

Comment: The issue was netbeans related. It ran fine when I compiled it as a Jar and ran it from the command line.

Comment: @David I don't think the issue is NetBeans related, but in managing threads, in fact you have removed the yield() invoking as I suggested you, and it works fine. I ran it from the command line, without compiling it as jar.