# Java - Happens before - volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model, happens-before

I have the below code

```
class VolatileCount {
    volatile int count;
    Object lock = new Object();

    public void increment() {

        synchronized (lock) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        System.out.print(" " + count);
    }

}
```

If I call `increment()` on same object from multiple threads I get the below output (might be different on your machine)

```
2 3 2 5 4 8 8 6 11 13 10 9 15 14 12 20 19
```

Looking at the repeating numbers I think *happens-before* seems to be broken, because considering first three number (2 3 2), if a thread sees 3 , increment has happened and since the variable is volatile, its value should be 3 or more but cannot be 2 in any thread.
However, the print line seems to have been reordered here, is it correct to reorder that line? What am I missing  here?  I run on JDK 7 (Eclipse)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023721/does-java-volatile-variables-impose-a-happens-before-relationship-before-it-is-r ?

Comment: consider 2 threads. First thread gets lock, increments count to 1 and releases the lock. Second thread gets lock, increments count to 2, releases lock, prints `2`, then first thread gets the value of count (now 2) to print it. in this case you would get `2 2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

Because you seem to want an explanation for the specific case of "2 3 2"

- X increments `i` (now 1)
- Y increments `i` (now 2)
- X reads `i` (X loads 2)
- Y reads `i` (Y loads 2)
- Y prints the value previously loaded (prints 2)
- Z increments `i`, reads `i`, prints `i` (prints 3)
- X prints the value previously loaded (prints 2)

The point is: `System.out.print(" " + count)` isn't atomic. The thread can be preempted after performing a volatile read and before printing the value.

If you want to prevent duplicate values from being printed, you have to perform the volatile read *inside* the lock:

```
public void increment() {
    int localCount;
    synchronized (lock) {
        count = count + 1;
        localCount = count; // volatile load
    }
    System.out.print(" " + localCount);
}
```

This wouldn't prevent values from being printed out of order though. In order to print them in order, without duplicates, you'd have to move the `print` into the lock as well.

### Old Answer

The print statement is outside the lock.
Consider the code running *inside* `System.out.print(" " + count)`.

- A thread X increments `i`
- Thread X evaluates the `print` arguments and performs a volatile read on the `count` variable, and loads the value `2`.
- Thread X is preempted by Thread Y, which increments `i`
- Thread Y loads `i` (which is now `3`), calls the print method which runs to completion.
- Thread Y is preempted, and Thread X now runs `print` to completion, which prints 2.

This would make the numbers show out of order, such as "3 2 4".

Some numbers might also be repeated when:

- Thread X increments `i` (which is now 2)
- Thread Y increments `i`(which is now 3)
- Thread X prints `i` (which is 3)
- Thread Y prints `i` (which is 3)

Comment: I understand it can be out of order, but I think it shouldn't repeat the numbers (unless its not allowed to reorder here)

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy I've added a case illustrating why some numbers would be repeated.

Comment: Well, since count is volatile and its been assigned a new value both the threads should see the latest value of 3. Both threads cannot read value to be same while incrementing anyways.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy my bad, i meant 3 instead of 2. But the point still stands. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I would accept this as answer as I too believe that its because of println that I saw the numbers out of order.

Answer (score 2):

consider 2 threads. First thread gets lock, increments count to `1` and releases the lock. Second thread gets lock, increments count to `2`, releases lock, prints 2, then first thread gets the value of count (now `2`) to print it. in this case you would get `2 2`

specifically to your example:

1. Thread A increments count to 1
2. Thread B increments it to 2
3. Thread A gets and prints value (2)
4. Thread B gets value (2)
5. Thread C inrements it to 3 and prints it
6. Thread B prints value (still 2 since that is what it got)

there you have `2 3 2`
etc...

Comment: I think I still have problem with that, as C has increased the number to 3 and since its volatile, it should still print 3. However I think as @mzf mentioned it might be eclipse doing its part. I will pursue this further.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy I've added another sequence of events explaining "2 3 2"

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy C does print 3, but it does it after B get the value(2) and before B prints 2. `println` is not in inself an atomic function and getting the value is in any case not part of the function itself. Think of the call to println as 1.read the value of `count` 2.pass that value as parameter to the function. Between steps 1 and 2 the value of count can be changed from another thread

Answer (score 1):

The problem may lay on the `System.out.print` multithreading 
check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554499/multithreading-problem-using-system-out-print-vs-println)  and maybe try running it form the command line , since your IDE may buffering the output

If you put the print inside the lock , it should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your printout is outside the protected zone. That means you may be interrupted any time between the increment and the print occurring, including after count has been fetched but before it has been sent to System.out. If you move that inside the synchronized block, I believe you'll see the behavior you expect.

Volatile is not a replacement for synchronization. It just warns the compiler that the value may change at any time and therefore should be fetched each time it's referenced rather than being optimized out.